# java call perl which read and write data

Tags: java, linux, perl

I have two files int the directory '/tmp': test.txt ,test.pl

the content of test.txt is :

```
abcdefg
```

the content of the test.pl is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
 chdir '/tmp';
 $data = `more test.txt`;
 open (MYFILE,">","newtest.txt") || die ("can not open this file");
 print  MYFILE $data;
```

Then in java class I write :

```
Process ps1= Runtime.getRuntime().exec("perl /tmp/test.pl ");
```

Then the content of the newtest.txt generated from the perl is :

```
::::::::::: 
test.txt 
:::::::::::
abcdefg
```

Here is the problem ,There is a difference

```
:::::::
test.txt
:::::::
```

but when I run 'perl test.pl' in linux , there is no difference between two files.

anyone knows the reason ? Thanks !

Comment: Thank you very very very much !  That is the reason ! I have been confused by this for whole day! I Accept my great admiration and worship !

Comment: You're welcome. I made an answer of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`more` is the guilty one here. It's intended for looking at a file one page at a time and waits for hitting e.g. <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to show the next page. Try `cat` instead of `more` to see if that is the reason.

`more` tries to be smart and autodetect whether it was called in an interactive situation but sometimes it fails. Depending on its settings it might behave as `cat` then, but you cannot be sure...